# How to remove index in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have found that I have two "survey_id" columns in my schema and that's been causing some problems for me. Specifically I need to remove the second index as I don't want survey_id to be unique.

```ruby
 add_index "completions", ["survey_id"], name: "index_completions_on_survey_id"
 add_index "completions", ["survey_id"], name: "index_completions_on_survey_id_and_user_id", unique: true
```

I've tried

```ruby
def change
  remove_index "completions", ["survey_id"], name => "index_completions_on_survey_id_and_user_id"
end
```

and

```
def change
  remove_index "completions", ["survey_id"], name: "index_completions_on_survey_id_and_user_id"
end
```

But neither of those seems to work. What's the correct syntax for this migration to remove the index? I feel like this is basic and I'm just missing something.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

You don't supply the columns in the index when removing one.  Try:

```
remove_index :completions, name: "index_completions_on_survey_id_and_user_id"
```

Comment: And if you're using Postgres, you might want to read up on the options, including `CONCURRENTLY`.

Comment: The columns aren't required when removing an index, but if this is in a `change` method and you want it to be reversible, you have to add the columns.

Answer (score 27):

The accepted answer here doesn't work when you need to roll back the migration, it will be given `ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration` error.

`remove_index` is only reversible if given a `:column` option.

```
def change
  remove_index "completions", column: [:survey_id], name: "index_completions_on_survey_id_and_user_id"
end
```

this will remove the index and also be reversible.

Answer (score 13):

From rails console, run following

```
ActiveRecord::Migration.remove_index "completions", name: "index_completions_on_survey_id_and_user_id"
```

Comment: This doesn't remove it from schema.rb though.

Comment: How do we specify the DB name when running this in the console?

Answer (score 9):

You can supply the column name(s) to `remove_index`. The `remove_index` method takes `table_name` and `options` as parameters. With the options passed in the name of the index is determined via `index_name_for_remove` private method, which simply does (if it is an array):

```
...
column_names = Array(options).map(&:to_s)
...

if column_names.any?
  checks << lambda { |i| i.columns.join('_and_') == column_names.join('_and_') }
end
```

Examples from the [API documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/v5.0.0.1/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/remove_index):

Removes the index on branch_id in the accounts table if exactly one such index exists.

```
remove_index :accounts, :branch_id
```

Or

```
remove_index :accounts, column: :branch_id
```

Removes the index on branch_id and party_id in the accounts table if exactly one such index exists.

```
remove_index :accounts, column: [:branch_id, :party_id]
```

Removes the index named by_branch_party in the accounts table.

```
remove_index :accounts, name: :by_branch_party
```

Apart from the above, you could just do:

```
remove_index :accounts, %i[branch_id party_id]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an expanded suggestion from Eric Walker to use `CONCURRENTLY` with PostgreSQL 12+ when removing indexes. I would have replied inline but the multiline code formatting wasn’t working.

Here’s Eric’s answer: [How to remove index in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745757/how-to-remove-index-in-rails#comment134477805_22745781)

Here, we’ll create a sample Rails Migration and call out three items needed when doing a index drop with the concurrently option:

- (1) Use `disable_ddl_transaction!` inside your migration, which is required when using `concurrently: true` later on
- (2) Check whether the index exists (optional, but nice if you’ve already removed it manually, but are using the migration to keep all DBs in sync)
- (3) Use `CONCURRENTLY` via Active Record (PG 12+)

```rb
class MyMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  disable_ddl_transaction! # (1)

  def change
    # (2) check existence below
    if index_exists?(:completions, [:survey_id, :user_id], name: 'index_completions_on_survey_id_and_user_id')
      remove_index :completions,
        name: "index_completions_on_survey_id_and_user_id"
        algorithm: :concurrently   # (3) use `CONCURRENTLY`
    end
  end
end
```

This migration was tested on a 6.0 Rails app, but in Rails 6.1 `if_exists: true` exists as an argument to `remove_index`, which is even nicer to use.

More info on `if_exists: true` https://blog.saeloun.com/2020/02/10/rails-support-for-if_exists-if_not_exists-on-remove_column-add_column-in-migrations/